# Is there a problem with my string replacement code?

Tags: python, string, loops, replace

```
string = input()

for i in range(len(string)):
    if i % 3 == 0:
        final = string.replace(string[i], "")

print(final)
```

> I was asked the question: "Given a string, delete all its characters whose indices are divisible by 3."
>
> The answer for the input `Python` is `yton`. However, my code gives `Pyton`.
>
> The code makes sense to me but I'm a beginner. Any help?

Comment: (1) You use the same `string` in each loop, so only the last change is reflected in `final`, and (2) You shouldn't use this method as it will fail if the string has repeating characters (i.e. you will remove all `h` characters, whether or not the indices of the other ones are divisible by 3).

Comment: `"".join(x for i, x in enumerate("Python") if i % 3 != 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that while you are looping, you are overriding the `final` variable every time the index is divisible by 3.
Instead, try defining the final variable before you start the loop, and add the letters as you loop over them, and only when they their index is NOT divisible by 3 (thus, ignoring the ones where the index IS divisible by 3).

Something like this should work:

```py
string = input()
final = ""
for i in range(len(string)):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        final += string[i]

print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, `final` is used through each iteration of the loop. It continues updating by replacing one character. In each iteration, `final` is replaced by a different string with one letter from `string` removed. After the loop has completed, it effectively only replaced one letter, which in this case is "h".

Use this instead (thanks to Mateen Ulhaq for the idea):

```
print("".join(x for i, x in enumerate(input()) if i % 3 != 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string=input()
final=""
for i in range(len(string)):
    if i % 3 != 0:
        final+=string[i]


print(final)
```

In your code, the line `final = string.replace(string[i], "")` would run like this.

Supposing the input is "hellobaby":

```
i=0, final="ellobaby"

i=3, final="helobaby"

i=6, final="hellobby"
```